# How to debounce a plain function call without "lodash" inside Angular httpClient errorCatch

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, angular-httpclient, rxjs-observables

I have a function that gets called inside Angular HttpClient catchError. I want to debounce the call to the function **without using Lodash**.
Cannot use **debounceTime** here since the function is not a subject. 
Is there a ES5/ES6 equivalent?

```
this.http.get(`api/test`)
  .pipe(
    catchError((err) => {
      alertUser(err); // Option 1 - debounce here 
      return throwError(err);
    }),
  );
```

```js
alertUser(err) {
  alert(err.text); // Option 2 - debounce here
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by "debounce" the function.. debouncing usually refers to putting a minimum time frame between successive function calls. Not clear what that would mean here as there seems to only be one function call.

Comment: Just put debounce on alertuser, what's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Not totally sure what you want... if you mean you want to delay the function for some reason, this is easy to do with `timer`

```
return timer(1000).pipe( // 1000 ms delay
  tap(t => alertUser(err)), // call this in tap
  switchMapTo(throwError(err)) // then throw the error again
);
```

if you truly want to debounce it with rxjs, and ensure it's only run every x number of seconds, you'll need to add in a subject to use, supposing you had some AlertService like:

```
private alertSource = new Subject();
alert$ = this.alertSource.pipe(debounceTime(1000)); //debounce the subject
constructor() {
  this.alert$.subscribe(err => alert(err)); // subscribe to it
}

alertUser(err) {
  this.alertSource.next(err); // send through subject
}
```

then just call your alert services alertUser function as needed.